# Copy comments from one excel sheet to another with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

i have a cell in one excel sheet which contains only a comment. I created it like this:

```
        CreationHelper factory = wb.getCreationHelper();
        Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        // When the comment box is visible, have it show in a 5x70 space
        ClientAnchor anchor = factory.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
        anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex()+5);
        anchor.setRow1(row.getRowNum());
        anchor.setRow2(row.getRowNum()+70);


        Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
        String text = "";
        RichTextString str = factory.createRichTextString(text);

        comment.setString(str);
        row.createCell(0).setCellComment(comment);
```

Now i have a new project, where I just want to copy that comment to a cell of another sheet, which should just work with that:

```
            XSSFRow row_master_a = null;
            XSSFRow row_slave_a = null;


            for(int j = 4;j<anz_neu+4;j++){
            row_master_a = sheet_master.getRow(4+anz_neu+3-j);
            if(row_master_a == null){
                row_master_a = sheet_master.createRow(4+anz_neu+3-j);
            }

            row_master_a.setHeightInPoints(40); 

            row_slave_a = sheet_slave.getRow(j);    

            row_master_a.createCell(0).setCellComment(row_slave_a.getCell(0).getCellComment());`
```

I don't get any errors, but I also don't have a comment in the new sheet.
Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a separate comment object and only copy the string contents as the Comment-object is tied to the Sheet.

I.e. something like

```
  Drawing drawing_master = sheet_master.createDrawingPatriarch();
  Comment comment_master = drawing_master.createCellComment(anchor);
  comment_master.setString(row_slave_a.getCell(0).getCellComment().getString());
  row_master_a.createCell(0).setCellComment(comment_master);
```

Comment: As with how CellStyles check you're assigning them to the correct Workbook + object if not, we should probably add a check that a Cell Comment object is being added to the correct (same) sheet to avoid this confusion...